# Write into slice references with map?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pass-by-reference

I am trying to write into Python slices that should have been passed to the function by reference.

```
def mpfunc(r):
    r[:]=1

R=np.zeros((2,4))

mpfunc(R[0])
mpfunc(R[1])
    
print(R)
```

This code works as expected. `R` contains `1` now.

When I use `map()`, however

```
def mpfunc(r):
    r[:]=1

R=np.zeros((2,4))

map(mpfunc,R)
    
R
```

it appears that the slices of `R` are not passed by reference anymore, which is not clear to me from the documentation. `R` now remains `0`.

Eventually, the goal is to use `multiprocessin.Pool.map()`, which unfortunately seems to fail for the same reasons:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mpfunc(r):
    r[:]=1

R=np.zeros((2,4))

with Pool(2) as p:
    p.map(mpfunc,R)
    
print(R)
```

Why is that and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the non-multiprocessing case you must *iterate* the *iterable* returned by the `map` function to ensure that the specified function has been applied to all the passed *iterables*. But this is not the case with `Pool.map`.

But what you have is a bigger problem. You are now passing your arrays to a process that lives in a different address space and there is no way that is can be done by reference unless the base `numpy` array is stored in shared memory.

In the following code, each process's global variable `R` will be initialized with a shared memory implementation of the `numpy` array. Now `map` function will be used with indices of this array that need to be updated:

```python
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import ctypes

def to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape):
    '''Create a numpy array backed by a shared memory Array.'''
    arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array)
    return arr.reshape(shape)

def to_shared_array(arr, ctype):
    shared_array = mp.Array(ctype, arr.size, lock=False)
    temp = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:] = arr.flatten(order='C')
    return shared_array

def init_worker(shared_array, shape):
    global R
    R = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)

def mpfunc(idx):
    R[idx, :] = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    R = np.zeros((2,4))
    shape = R.shape
    shared_array = to_shared_array(R, ctypes.c_int64)
    # you have to now use the shared array as the base
    R = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)

    with mp.Pool(2, initializer=init_worker, initargs=(shared_array, shape)) as p:
        p.map(mpfunc, range(shape[0]))

    print(R)
```

Prints:

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: Okay, now I get the problem. While the other two comments were very helpful explaining the iterable issue, I'll mark this one as the solution since it also comments on my multiprocessing issue. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

`map` (in Python 3) is lazy, you need to consume it to trigger function, consider following simple example:

```
def update_dict(dct):
    dct.update({"x":1})
data = [{"x":0},{"x":0},{"x":0}]
mp = map(update_dict, data)
print(data)
lst = list(map(update_dict, data))
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'x': 0}, {'x': 0}, {'x': 0}]
[{'x': 1}, {'x': 1}, {'x': 1}]
```

Keep in mind that if possible, you should avoid calling `map` for side effects, to avoid bafflement of other people working on this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just calling a map function it just created a generator object for you and it hasn't actually completed its call. A generator is a Python way of delayed or lazy execution.
So this is one of the ways you could do it.

```
    ...: def mpfunc(r):
    ...:    r[:]=1
    ...: 
    ...: R=np.zeros((2,4))
    ...: 
    ...: # mpfunc(R[0])
    ...: # mpfunc(R[1])
    ...: list(map(mpfunc, R))
    ...:
    ...: print(R)
```

Just consume the map function either by creating a list or whatsoever method that suits you. Ideally a `next()` function is used to consume it one by one.

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

The same would work for your multiprocess snippet too.